# Chromatic Tones

Tags: cipher, visual

An artist recently painted this odd looking mural in my hometown. He called it 'Chromatic Tones'. Most people just walk by it, but I suspect it has a deeper meaning. I have looked at it, increasingly frustrated, over the past few days, but I can't make anything out of it!

[image]

**Can you decode it?**
<sub>If you're stuck, I suggest calling a friend!</sub>

Comment: I like it very much, but I'm surprised it was answered within the hour!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mural reads:

> It was a bright cold day in April and the clocks were striking thirteen.

Things to note:

> The dots come in groups of one to four of the same colour. There is never more than one group of a colour per 3×3 panel. There's a red dot in every panel. If there are more groups, they are orange, yellow and so on. Only two panels have black dots. The top left square is always empty.

The mural is encoded like this:

> Each 3×3 panel represents a word. Each group of dots represents a letter. The letters are ordered by the colours of the rainbow (ROY G BIV) plus black for the eighth letter. A letter is described by the number of dots per group and their position inside the panel: The panel grid resembles a telephone keypad, and the hint supports this. The top left key (1) doesn't have any letters assigned and the only occurrence of four letters is in the bottom left square, one of the two keys (7 and 9) with four letters assigned.

Comment: Your solution is the first line of the book _Nineteen Eighty-Four_.

Comment: While the solution is accepted and correct (how did you get it that fast?), I find the given answer not all-too-easy to read and understand. I think a step-wise example of how one "box" is completely decoded would add a lot to this answer. For now, I -1 tis answer despite it being correct. I will revert this vote to a +1 on edits.

Comment: @BmyGuest Let's take the first 3x3 box: We start with the Red dots (since Red is first in ROYGBIV color sequence) which are in the spot corresponding to 4 on a phone keypad. Conventionally, 4 maps to the letters GHI on phones. Since there are *three* dots, that indicates the *third* letter, I, is the first letter of the word. Next is Orange. One dot on 8 (TUV) means the second letter is T. Combine to get the first word: IT. Each 3x3 box is another word.

Comment: "Chromatic Tones" is a clue since it's a code based on colors and a touch-tone keypad.

Comment: @Sabre: Thanks. However, I meant MOehm should edit such info into his solution.

Comment: @randal'thor: Thanks. I didn't spot the reference to Nineteen Eighty-Four. (But I think that book is more famous for its last sentence rather than its first.)

Comment: @BmyGuest well now he can copy-paste my comment if he wants, save himself the effort ;)

Comment: @BmyGuest: I agree that the answer could be presented in a better way, but I have problems to mark up good paragraph and list formats inside a spoiler. I know I could chop everything into small chunks and have a lot of "Now we see that" and "With that information, we get" semi-paragraphs between the protected chunks, but that's not very clear or pretty either in my opinion.

Comment: @MOehm I was actually thinking of a snippet like Sabre's. The format isn't that important. A picture of a phone pad would be useful, but not needed.